# Приветствие "здорово"

Tags: окончания

Почему пишется "здоров**о**", а не "здоров**а**"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этикетное приветствие слово "здор**о**во" конвертировалось из  качественного прилагательного при помощи суффикса *о*.

На скрине видны синонимы - *хорошо, благополучно*. Эти наречия отвечают на вопрос *как?*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отличный ответ! Только я не пойму, какое ударение в этих примерах. Так же, здорОво, или здОрово?

Comment: ЗдорОво. Прямая связь со здоровьем.